# Go AWS SDK's DeleteObject Method Hanging Without Returning Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am experiencing an issue with the AWS SDK for Go where the `DeleteObject` method hangs indefinitely without returning any errors. (I am able to delete buckets flawlessly in most cases, this hanging issue occurs with some specific buckets.) My program successfully deletes a certain number of objects from an S3 bucket but then gets stuck without any indication of what might be wrong.

I have already implemented comprehensive error handling to catch both Go **`error`** and **`awserr.Error`** types, but the issue persists. The program hangs after deleting a specific number of objects (e.g., 50), and no error is logged or returned.

I've considered potential issues like network problems, AWS service health, SDK bugs, and rate limiting but haven't been able to identify the cause.

```
_, err := svc.DeleteObject(&s3.DeleteObjectInput{
                        Bucket:    aws.String(creds.Bucket),
                        Key:       task.Key,
                        VersionId: task.VersionId,
                    })
                    if err != nil {
                        logger.Log(fmt.Sprintf("Error occurred: %s", err), creds.Mail)

                        if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
                            // Process AWS SDK error
                            logger.Log(fmt.Sprintf("AWS SDK Error occurred: %s, Code: %s, Message: %s", awsErr.Error(), awsErr.Code(), awsErr.Message()), creds.Mail)
                            if awsErr.Code() == "AccessDenied" {
                                // Specific handling for AccessDenied
                                sendJSONWebSocketMessage(ws, progressMessage{
                                    Progress: float64(deletedObjects) / float64(totalObjects) * 100,
                                    Message:  fmt.Sprintf("ACCESS DENIED, stopping: %s", awsErr.Error()),
                                })
                                return
                            }
                        }

                        sendJSONWebSocketMessage(ws, progressMessage{
                            Progress: float64(deletedObjects) / float64(totalObjects) * 100,
                            Message:  fmt.Sprintf("Error deleting object/marker, retrying in 3 seconds: %s", err),
                        })
                        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
                        continue
                    }
```